# Batching generator input in for loop

Tags: python, generator

I have a really long input stream, which I read line by line with the generator. Organizing data in batches greatly helps with the processing rate. The data reading loop approximately looks like this:

```
# Create tuple stream generator (an example, not the real code)
input_gen = ( (vals[0], vals[0]) for block in input_file for vals in block.split() )  

while True:
  batch = tuple(itertools.isslice(input_gen, 42)) # 42 is the batch size
  if len(batch) == 0:
    break
  # process batch
```

The `while`-`if` construction looks cumbersome. Whether it is possible to organize the code with a simple `for` loop?

For example:

```
for batch in <some_expression>:
  # process batch
```

Comment: Python 3.8 was released in 2019, can you still not use it yet?

Comment: I can. How this helps?

Comment: `while batch := tuple(...):`

Comment: It works, but I still believe it can be done with `for`

Comment: Yes, it can be done with `for`, but unless you write or install a function specifically for this, it won't be better. Just to be sure: You realize that with the above, you don't need the `if` anymore, right?

Comment: No, no `if` for that Pascal syntax. Looks so 90s, haha.

Comment: Hooray for the walrus! `(:3｣∠)_`

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to wrap your generator into a "chunking" function:

```py
from itertools import islice

def chunk(it, size):
    it = iter(it)
    return iter(lambda: tuple(islice(it, size)), ())
```

```py
>>> from itertools import count
>>> c = chunk(count(666), 13)
>>> next(c)
(666, 667, 668, 669, 670, 671, 672, 673, 674, 675, 676, 677, 678)
>>> next(c)
(679, 680, 681, 682, 683, 684, 685, 686, 687, 688, 689, 690, 691)
```

Since `chunk` returns an iterator, using `for` with it is the most natural thing to do:

```py
>> for c in chunk(count(666), 13):
...     s = sum(c)
...     print(s)
...     if s > 10_000:
...         break
...
8736
8905
9074
9243
9412
9581
9750
9919
10088
```

Here I had to break, because otherwise we'll be `sum`ming infinitely (since `count()` returns an infinite iterator).  It would work as expected with finite iterators, too:

```py
>>> for c in chunk(range(69), 13):
...     print(sum(c))
...
78
247
416
585
754
266
```

---

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22045226/9288580), you can also read about other approaches to "chunking" and padding issues there.

Comment: Your current example doesn't demonstrate that it ends well. I suggest you use a short `range` instead of `count`+`break`.

Comment: Good point, @KellyBundy, I didn't think of that.  My usual concern with similar solutions is whether it works with (potentially) infinite iterators, because lots of people like to slice or `len()` or `list()` them.  I've added another example.